# Frame rate of Camera2 API are coming below of 1 for some of device of Samsung

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, frame-rate, android-camera2

I am using Camera2 with MediaRecorder. For **30 sec recorded video**, the length of the video is coming as **8-9 hours**.

When we analyzed, we saw that the frame rate of the video is coming as 0.01 FPS. This is happening only in some of the devices of Samsung like J6, J7.

I am also not able to replicate this issue also.

Here is my code for setting MediaRecorder configuration

```
 mediaRecorder?.apply {
        setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
        setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE)
        setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)
        setOutputFile(nextVideoAbsolutePath)
        setVideoEncodingBitRate(1000000)
        setVideoSize(320, 240)
        setVideoFrameRate(20)
        setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264)
        setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC)
        prepare()
    }
```

Comment: Do you have actual output you can post here? This doesn't sound to me like a "really slow camera". It sounds more like "video recorded normally for a certain period of time, but a mastering problem or camera fault caused the recording to have an unusually long duration, most of which was empty".

Comment: Sorry, I can't post the video because it's confidential. Basically In file audio is recording is coming for 30 sec. but the length of the video is coming as 3-4 hours.

and only 1st frame is going on for all the 3-4 hour long video.

Comment: It sounds like you know how to pick apart an .mp4 file. Why don't you describe your methodology, and post some of your analysis.